# assembleDebug fails indicating errors on one file, even after fixing said errors

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

My current Flutter project fails during the `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...` step and it points me to some errors in one of the .dart files. The issue is that even after fixing some of them, it keeps throwing the same errors.

**Dart with three errors**

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/helpers/crawler.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/models/source/search_result.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/models/state.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/routes/crawler_novel.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/widgets/navigation.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class RouteCrawlerResults extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String routeName = '/crawler/results';

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new RouteCrawlerResultsState();
}

class RouteCrawlerResultsState extends State<RouteCrawlerResults> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Search Results')),
      body: _crawlerResultsBody(context),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavBar(context),
    );
  }
}

Widget _crawlerResultsBody(BuildContext context) {
  Future<Map<Uri, List<SearchResult>>> getResults() async {
    CrawlerHelper crawler = CrawlerHelper.instance;
    CrawlerSearchState provider =
        Provider.of<CrawlerSearchState>(context, listen: false);
    Map<Uri, List<SearchResult>> searchResults =
        await crawler.searchNovels(provider.serachQuery);
    return searchResults;
  }

  return FutureBuilder(
      future: getResults(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<Map<Uri, List<SearchResult>>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Center(
            child: Text('Fetching results.'),
          );
        else {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error fetching results.'));
          }
          /*if (snapshot.data.entries.length == 0) {
            return Center(child: Text('No results.'));
          }*/
          CrawlerSearchState provider =
              Provider.of<CrawlerSearchState>(context, listen: false);
          provider.searchResults = snapshot.data;
          return _crawlerResultsList(context);
        }
      });
}

Widget _crawlerResultsList(BuildContext context) {
  CrawlerSearchState provider =
      Provider.of<CrawlerSearchState>(context, listen: false);

  List<SearchResult> searchResults = provider.searchResults.entries
      .map((entry) {
        return entry.value;
      })
      .toList()
      .expand((element) => element)
      .toList();

  return ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
    children: [
      ...searchResults
          .map((result) => _crawlerResultsListItem(context, result))
          .toList()
    ],
  );
}

Widget _crawlerResultsListItem(BuildContext context, SearchResult result) {
  ReaderState state =
      Provider.of<ReaderState>(context, listen: false);

  CrawlerSearchState crawlerSearchState =
      Provider.of<CrawlerSearchState>(context, listen: false);

  void onTap() {
    crawlerSearchState.resultSelected = result;
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteCrawlerNovel.routeName);
  }

  return InkWell(
    onTap: onTap,
    child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
        height: 120,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        ),
        child: Flex(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Flexible(
                flex: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                        result.cover.toString(),
                        cacheManager: state .cacheManager,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            SizedBox(
              width: 15,
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 10,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Text(
                      result.title,
                      maxLines: 3,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize * 1.2),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      flex: 0,
                      child: Text(
                        result.source.toString(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            )
          ],
        )),
  );
}
```

**Console errors**

```
/E:/Archivo/Estudio/Git/reader_app/lib/routes/crawler_results.dart:52:29: Error: Property 'entries' cannot be accessed on 'Map<Uri, List<SearchResult>>?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'SearchResult' is from 'package:reader_app/models/source/search_result.dart' ('lib/models/source/search_result.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
          if (snapshot.data.entries.length == 0) {
                            ^^^^^^^
/E:/Archivo/Estudio/Git/reader_app/lib/routes/crawler_results.dart:142:69: Error: Property 'fontSize' cannot be accessed on 'TextStyle?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'TextStyle' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/text_style.dart' ('/C:/Android/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize *
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^
/E:/Archivo/Estudio/Git/reader_app/lib/routes/crawler_results.dart:142:78: Error: Operator '*' cannot be called on 'double?' because it is potentially null.
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize *
                                                                             ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Dart with code causing third error ( double? * 1.2 ) removed:**

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/helpers/crawler.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/models/source/search_result.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/models/state.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/routes/crawler_novel.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/widgets/navigation.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class RouteCrawlerResults extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String routeName = '/crawler/results';

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new RouteCrawlerResultsState();
}

class RouteCrawlerResultsState extends State<RouteCrawlerResults> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Search Results')),
      body: _crawlerResultsBody(context),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavBar(context),
    );
  }
}

Widget _crawlerResultsBody(BuildContext context) {
  Future<Map<Uri, List<SearchResult>>> getResults() async {
    CrawlerHelper crawler = CrawlerHelper.instance;
    CrawlerSearchState provider =
        Provider.of<CrawlerSearchState>(context, listen: false);
    Map<Uri, List<SearchResult>> searchResults =
        await crawler.searchNovels(provider.serachQuery);
    return searchResults;
  }

  return FutureBuilder(
      future: getResults(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<Map<Uri, List<SearchResult>>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Center(
            child: Text('Fetching results.'),
          );
        else {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error fetching results.'));
          }
          /*if (snapshot.data.entries.length == 0) {
            return Center(child: Text('No results.'));
          }*/
          CrawlerSearchState provider =
              Provider.of<CrawlerSearchState>(context, listen: false);
          provider.searchResults = snapshot.data;
          return _crawlerResultsList(context);
        }
      });
}

Widget _crawlerResultsList(BuildContext context) {
  CrawlerSearchState provider =
      Provider.of<CrawlerSearchState>(context, listen: false);

  List<SearchResult> searchResults = provider.searchResults.entries
      .map((entry) {
        return entry.value;
      })
      .toList()
      .expand((element) => element)
      .toList();

  return ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
    children: [
      ...searchResults
          .map((result) => _crawlerResultsListItem(context, result))
          .toList()
    ],
  );
}

Widget _crawlerResultsListItem(BuildContext context, SearchResult result) {
  ReaderState state =
      Provider.of<ReaderState>(context, listen: false);

  CrawlerSearchState crawlerSearchState =
      Provider.of<CrawlerSearchState>(context, listen: false);

  void onTap() {
    crawlerSearchState.resultSelected = result;
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteCrawlerNovel.routeName);
  }

  return InkWell(
    onTap: onTap,
    child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
        height: 120,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        ),
        child: Flex(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Flexible(
                flex: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                        result.cover.toString(),
                        cacheManager: state .cacheManager,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            SizedBox(
              width: 15,
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 10,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Text(
                      result.title,
                      maxLines: 3,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      flex: 0,
                      child: Text(
                        result.source.toString(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            )
          ],
        )),
  );
}
```

**Console after trying to run things again**

```
/E:/Archivo/Estudio/Git/reader_app/lib/routes/crawler_results.dart:52:29: Error: Property 'entries' cannot be accessed on 'Map<Uri, List<SearchResult>>?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'SearchResult' is from 'package:reader_app/models/source/search_result.dart' ('lib/models/source/search_result.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
          if (snapshot.data.entries.length == 0) {
                            ^^^^^^^
/E:/Archivo/Estudio/Git/reader_app/lib/routes/crawler_results.dart:142:69: Error: Property 'fontSize' cannot be accessed on 'TextStyle?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'TextStyle' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/text_style.dart' ('/C:/Android/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize *
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^
/E:/Archivo/Estudio/Git/reader_app/lib/routes/crawler_results.dart:142:78: Error: Operator '*' cannot be called on 'double?' because it is potentially null.
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize *
                                                                             ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Disregard the first two errors about properties of potentially null objects (which are still weird) but check the third one about `'*' cannot be called on 'double?'`. I removed the operation entirely but it still throws the same error.  Dunno why, but nothing I do to the file changes things. I tried deleting the file just to see what would happen and, while throwing other errors about some references being broken, it still gives me the deleted file errors.

I tried running Invalidate caches / restart, deleting user/.gradle/caches, gradlew clean, creating a new flutter project and copying the lib folder (and the dependencies inside pubspec.yaml), and reinstalling Android Studio, but nothing worked. The only stuff I did before this error that could have something to do with this were updating flutter, moving the project folder, and forcefully powering off the pc during the last assembleDebug due to the machine becoming unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Another dart file had an absolute path import reference to the file instead of the package:... type import. It was pointing to the old file before I copied the project.

**Other .dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/helpers/crawler.dart';
import 'file:///E:/Archivo/Estudio/Git/reader_app/lib/routes/crawler_results.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/models/state.dart';
import 'package:reader_app/widgets/navigation.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
```